# fetch_lfw_people error on changing parameters (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm following this example on the sklean doc [sklearn_doc](http://scikit-learn.org/0.15/auto_examples/applications/face_recognition.html) ,I can execute the example but if I change  from:

```
fetch_lfw_people(min_faces_per_person=70, resize=0.4)
```

to

```
fetch_lfw_people(min_faces_per_person=200, resize=1.0)
```

I'haven't changed anything but this parameters  ,is an int for another int and a float for another float,I can't see the problem

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tema4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/lfw.py", line 144, in _load_imgs
    from scipy.misc import imread
ImportError: cannot import name 'imread'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py", line 19, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tema4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/lfw.py", line 146, in _load_imgs
    from scipy.misc.pilutil import imread
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py", line 21, in <module>
    import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/practica/ejercicio1.py", line 25, in <module>
    lfw_people = fetch_lfw_people(min_faces_per_person=200, resize=1.0)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tema4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/lfw.py", line 335, in fetch_lfw_people
    min_faces_per_person=min_faces_per_person, color=color, slice_=slice_)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tema4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/memory.py", line 562, in __call__
    return self._cached_call(args, kwargs)[0]
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tema4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/memory.py", line 510, in _cached_call
    out, metadata = self.call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tema4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/memory.py", line 744, in call
    output = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tema4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/lfw.py", line 236, in _fetch_lfw_people
    faces = _load_imgs(file_paths, slice_, color, resize)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tema4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/lfw.py", line 149, in _load_imgs
    raise ImportError("The Python Imaging Library (PIL)"
ImportError: The Python Imaging Library (PIL) is required to load data from jpeg files
```

Comment: Do you have PIL installed?